# Woocommerce [products] shortcode - How to order by given product ids atribute?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get products list (html), using Woocommerce default `[products]` shortcode, like that:

```
$product_ids = '1,2,3,4,5';
$content = do_shortcode( '[products ids="'.$product_ids.'" columns="3"]' );
```

This shortcode returns a correct html product list. The problem is with order. It returns products ordered by date (default). But I need order exactly like passed.

If this had been done using default Wordpress `WP_Query` it would be that way:

```
'post__in' => $product_ids ,
'orderby'  => 'post__in'
```

But using WC shortcode, I can't find a way to reproduce this. I'm trying to find actions or filters within WC Shortcode Classes, but without success.

Anyone knows how can I edit the WC Shortcodes query to add the param `'orderby'  => 'post__in'`?

Comment: Have you tried `do_shortcode( '[products orderby="id" ids="'.$product_ids.'" columns="3"]' );` ?

Comment: Hello @JasvinderSingh! Yes, I tried. This param order by posts IDs in database, not the order inside `ids` param. Unfortunately, doesn't works.

Comment: Just simply pass `orderby="post__in"` in your shortcode attribute

Comment: @itzmekhokan Unbelievable! It works! And it's not documented in WooCommerce Shortcodes Page. Can you post as answer for me to accept?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your do_shortcode code with follows -

```
$content = do_shortcode( '[products ids="'.$product_ids.'" columns="3" orderby="post__in"]' );
```